# Is it possible to turn off activities in an AWS Data Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline, bigdata

We are building a production data pipeline that runs batch jobs (AWS Data Pipeline Activities) dynamically depending on their dependencies.  Apart from running the whole data pipeline, we would like to run a specific section of the pipeline and adhoc single activities.

1) Is it possible to run an AWS Data Pipeline with some activities turned off?

2) Is there a way to run a single activity from the existing AWS Data Pipeline?

Comment: Sounds like you are not building a pipeline but a workflow. I think, it is quite common for us developers to think about computing in terms of control-flow. But in my experience, that is not the right abstraction for a data pipeline. I suggest, you either revisit your requirements or pick another tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the status of the activities you do not want to run to finished before they run. This will prevent them from running.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/APIReference/API_SetStatus.html

Another possibility is to create multiple pipelines.